# How to hydrate tweets with Python?

Tags: python, twitter, hydration, twarc2

I want to hydrate a covid-19 tweets id CSV file. I try to follow https://theneuralblog.com/hydrating-tweet-ids/ for the hydration.
I'm using Jupyter notebook, running line by line. But there is an error when I code:

```py
for tweet in t.hydrate(open('/Users/peggyleung95/Desktop/FYP/Untitled Folder/corona_tweets_theta.csv')):
    print(tweet['text'])
    print(tweet['id'])
    
    if tweet['place']:
        print(tweet['place']['country'])
```

An error msg showing:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 t = Twarc(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
2 for tweet in t.hydrate(open('/Users/peggyleung95/Desktop/FYP/Untitled Folder/corona_tweets_theta.csv')):
----> 3     print(tweet['text'])
4     print(tweet['id'])
5

KeyError: 'text'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your for loop is indented correctly:

```
for tweet in t.hydrate(open('/Users/peggyleung95/Desktop/FYP/Untitled Folder/corona_tweets_theta.csv')):
    print(tweet['text'])
    print(tweet['id'])

    if tweet['place']:
        print(tweet['place']['country'])
```

Comment: Yes, it's indented correctly